# Emacs Nox End of File

Tags: pantheon-terminal, command-line, editor

Just installed Loki, coming from Ubuntu Gnome.

Installed emacs-nox:

`sudo apt install emacs-nox`

As expected `emacs` opens my editor, but when I edit a file I often immediatley enter `meta-shift-?` (`meta-shift-/`) to go to the end of the file.

The Shift isn't registering for some reason. What am I missing? I don't want to search for a tag, I want to go to the end of the file.